# if key exists: update, otherwise: assoc

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

consider this inside a reduce loop:

```
(if (contains? m k)
  (update m k conj v)
  (assoc m k [v]))
```

Is there a way to get rid of the if statement?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `fnil` to handle the nil value of `v` when `k` doesn't exist in the map:

```
(update m k (fnil conj []) v)
```

Comment: took me some time to grasp it, but yes! got it now, great answer!

Comment: shazam, nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

While the `fnil` answer is more spectacular, I find the following easier to read, especially if unfamiliar with `fnil`:

```
(assoc m k (conj (m k []) v))
```

where `(m k [])` returns the value of `k` in `m` or defaults to `[]` if `k` does not exist in `m`.

If `k` is a symbol, `(k m [])` would also work.